# How to call smart contract function when the owners address receives ethers?

Tags: solidity, tokens, ether, smart-contract-wallets

A token ERC-20 smart contract can call functions when the transfer() function is called to send or receive tokens. I can test if is the owner address and make things.

Its possible that my smart contract know if the owner address receives ethers (no tokens) and call a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement in your code a PAYABLE function that accepts Ether and transfer it to the owner's account

```
function deposit() public payable {
    require(msg.value > 0);
    Owner_Address.transfer(msg.value);
    /* Make your things ;) */
}
```

Comment: Oh, interesting and easy way, thank you